Does riding a single-speed provide a more rounded workout?
This question considers only short-ride (10-20 km) workouts.
After trying single-speed riding, I'm questioning the value of working out using a derailleur-equipped bicycle.
Having access to a derailleur makes me

remain in almost exactly the same cadence (85-90),
produce what is likely almost exactly the same power, and
with little variation in my heartbeat (since on a short ride I go all out from beginning to end),
plus my leg muscles remain in the same "stretch zone" (I am seated throughout).

On a single-speed

my cadence changes from the minimal needed to remain balanced (40-60) to a furious 120 on descents.
The pressure I put on pedals is either the most I can produce, or it's trivial.
My heartbeat is either at my upper limit, or I am resting because I give up pedaling on downhills while I'm unable to keep up with the speed.
My legs are either taking a break, or I have to stand to push hard enough on the climbs.

Something else makes single speed very attractive. Cycling is inherently a leg workout. I normally have to supplement it with some upper body workout. On a single speed I am wrestling with the handlebar and frame, and can subsequently feel the tension and improved tone.
Does riding a single-speed provide a superior workout?
The one factor that ultimately matters is the average speed. On my standard 10 to 20 km rides, my average speed using a single-speed is higher (not by much, just ~2 kph, but higher nevertheless) than when shifting, which I tend to do often. I am puzzled at this increase in average speed, and am still trying to figure out how to analyze rides to determine whether the rests I take downhills and the intensity I put on climbs is the cause (to quote the refrain: "races are won on the climbs").
If you've read all the way to here, plan to contribute an answer, and can suggest ways to achieve the same average speed using a derailleur-equipped bike (relax more on descents?; save the energy for the climbs?; ...?), please do.
Clarification (edit 1)
The "single-speed" is actually the same bike, and so the experiment is proper — same weight, same friction in the pulleys, etc. A real single speed would have at least one advantage: the chainring and the sprocket would be coplanar.
(It happened by accident. My RD cable was fraying, but I was determined to ride that day with that bike. That's how this single-speed simulation started.)
What makes one workout “superior” to another? (edit 2)
With a car we can reasonably say that one engine is superior to another if it leads to a higher average speed — with the same chassis, driver, and course.
Since on a bike the engine is the human, we can likewise say that the human is becoming a better machine if we set the conditions for a consistently higher average speed — on the same bike and over the same path. An additional point is whether a “better machine” means a “superior workout“. You’re more than welcome to refute this.
Related (edit 3; after reading the many fine answers)
The answer to another question
Why are responses to an attack in a cycling race immediate?
is becoming a lot clearer. If one racer has designed his speed over a stage’s harder climbs, his competitor cannot afford to slack off on any given tough climb. The race may ultimately be determined by whether he does. If he does need to relax at some point, he can choose to just coast on the descents.

What's stopping you from producing more power or standing up when you're able to change gears?

What is your normal variation on that route, what is you sample size (please don't say 1 ride).  Is your 2km/h variation within 1 or 5 standard deviations?

You don't need single-speed for a coplanar chainring/sprocket; hub or bottom bracket gears also work.

@PaulH's point is a good one, but it does depend on the geometry as well.  For example I generally find standing to pedal more sensible on flat bars (though I generally find it unreasonably tiring)

Regarding edit 2, and I hint at this in my answer, I think your ride could be called superior on the SS, but calling it a superior workout is going too far (as "workout" generally refers to training, i.e. the effect on your future ability)

"Cycling is inherently a leg workout." Disagree. Cycling is inherently a cardio workout.

@gerrit you’re not wrong, but hub and gearbox systems aren’t generally found on performance oriented road/gravel bikes, and their efficiencies are inferior to single speeds and (nominally maintained) derailleur systems.

Depending on which gears you choose when, you could make the same route intentionally harder or intentionally easier on a multi-geared bike than a fixed-gear.

Voted to close - Please stop adding edits that invalidate the already given answers.

"The one factor that ultimately matters is the average speed"
No. Depending where you put the power (descents/climbs/headwind/tailwind) on all but a flat, windless course you can achieve the same average speed with a wide variety of powers. It's power at the pedals that matters, in terms of a workout

Not an answer to your question, but: rather than single speed, look at fixed gear. On a single speed you can freewheel; on fixed gear you cannot. You are then getting a workout on downhills, too - and learning good souplesse (to be able to spin legs at 160rpm safely) or backpedalling (to slow yourself down). The benefit of single speed vs derailleur is lower complexity. The benefit of fixed gear is increasing leg strength. A similar effect happens on indoor trainers, where pressure must be maintained on the pedals or the turbo slows quickly.

@user7761803 Would a fixed-gear beginner still opt for clipless pedals, or would using flat pedals be advisable to bail out of spinning by those unaccustomed to these hypersonic RPMs?

@mattnz If you remove the “it could be a different bike” from your answer, it remains not just valid, but close to the checked answer (but I can only checkmark one answer).

@PaulH On a geared bike nothing stops me from putting (much) more power on climbs, but I’ve always perceived this to be a bad idea (risk of early exhaustion on the ride, injury from grinding my knees, time to recover before the next ride). I always aimed for using constant power throughout a course. What this experiment is suggesting is that I need to put maybe 74% of the energy I start with on the climbs, 24% (maybe) on the flats, and basically let gravity do its thing on the descents, with me just getting the “ball rolling” (or rather the wheels).

Comment only: You could try different ratios for you SS simulation. My 1st bike (over 60 years ago :-) ) was a very high  geared heavy single speed. It seemed to keep up with others OK. With effort I could JUST climb the steepest local hills by pulling on the handlebars while standing on the pedals. Certainly a superior workout compared to my later (oh bliss :-) ) 3 speed. Trying very low and very high ratios may be useful and each may have merit for different training aspects. || We also had an optional fixed gear bike - ex my father. Not something I'd ride without exceptionally good reason.

@RussellMcMahon I'll be cautious and comment here rather than explain in the body of the question — to avoid that more people would curse me and my question for adding more details. Yes! That's the beauty of using an "SS simulator" rather than an actual SS. I can identify after just one ride that a gear ratio is simply not workable, and can focus subsequent experiments on the one gear ratio that enables the fastest average speed. How do I discard a gear ratio as too hard? Easy. I can't ride up-hills nimbly enough. I'm still unsure how I can discard a gear ratio as too easy. (tbc..)

@RussellMcMahon (cont.) One French word introduced in this Q&A is souplesse. Does practicing with a slightly easy gear ratio improve one's "souplesse" to the point of making that gear ratio the best one for a given course? That's one of my next experiments.

'On a single speed I am wrestling with the handlebar and frame, and can subsequently feel the tension and improved tone.' Well, you could do the same on a geared bike, you're just too lazy to do it - not meant to be mean, I suffer from the same issue. It's just something you'd actively have to use, with the single speed you are forced to, but nothing stops you from doing the same on a geared bike.

@Arsenal That's not mean at all, but it's pretty obvious. On a geared bike I'd need a reminder to do it.

No, you do not get a superior workout on a single speed, but it constrains you to do with what you have, and gives you a different workout.
If you go faster on a single speed bike, you are probably not using gears in the most efficient manner. More gears make it possible to smooth out the required effort while maximizing the average speed. Most humans are most efficient within a reasonable range of cadence, which is impossible to obtain with a single ratio if there are steeper sections on a ride. The body is also more efficient at a fairly constant effort instead of insane bursts with intermittent breaks (no record is run, swum or ridden the latter way that I know of).
Yes, spending a lot of energy downhill is wasteful as the drag is proportional to the velocity squared. So if you need some periods of lower intensity you should take them when you are going fast anyway (downhill). For a similar reason you want to limit the dip in speed when going uphill if you want to get a maximum average speed, as it is disproportionally (due to drag, and the kinetic energy) difficult to make up for spent time when the speed is higher (flats/downhill). There is not much more to it.
Perhaps your single speed has better tires/bearings etc, a lower position, or just a more enthusiastic rider? Anyway, just ride what you like the way you like it.

The SS is likely to be a bit lighter, perhaps by enough to make climbs faster.  As you've established, that helps quite a bit with the average speed. There are also very slight losses in the jockey wheels of the rear mech

Yes, ligther, but I assume he starts and finishes at the same elevation so the little saved weight should not account for 2kph average. But of course, if he has a superlight carbon single speed, and a heavy tank of a steel geared bike then perhaps that is all there is. My post was just getting too long.

There's also a little saving in drag from not having a rear mech, but the combination of faster climbing (due to lower weight) and enforced resting on descents (meaning more power on the next climb) is helpful

You’re basically hitting the nail on the head. You’re suggesting I should be able to reach, or even beat, the same average speed with a geared bike, but I would have to be more deliberate about the choice of gears on the climbs and to be more careful about taking rests on downhills. Even on the briefest (10-km) workout, there’s only so much energy that a given rider can supply, and improving one’s record requires designing the speeds over the course’s segments.

It will take me at least three weeks to ride the ten or so experiments needed to reach any sensible conclusions, and likely much longer if the ground freezes or it snows and I need to switch to a less nimble bike and tires.

@ChrisH Sure all valid points. If the route is flat you don't need more than 1 gear. If it's flat enough, 1 gear benefits might outweigh having multiple gears. But for most scenarios where the route is not too short and flat, multiple gears will be superior.

@WornChain I'm certainly with you on that conclusion.  I like my gears (to the extent of preferring 3 chainrings). But many of my long-distance friends (e.g. about 50% on a 400km/24hr event) ride fixed even in hills, and are quick too - which says more about the riders than the bikes.

@ChrisH I like 3x as well, but 2x would cover 98% of my usage. I don't really like the modern 1x setups for a variety of reasons. If you are young and/or strong single speed might be great, but it forces you to ride in different manner and offers less flexibility.

Modern training methodology is all about making your training as controlled as possible.
When your training program prescribes a 4 hour ride in zone 2, you ideally spend the full 4 hours in zone 2. With a geared bike you can get close to this ideal, even on a hilly route or on a windy day.
When your training program prescribes a 5 minute interval workout a geared bike allows you to pick just the right intensity.
With a single speed bike you lose all this control.
I think a single speed bike could have training benefits for people who actually don’t want to train and always use easy gears. With a single speed they would be forced to spend some effort, at least when accelerating or going uphill.

The assumptions on the "derailleur" are somehow flawed to me. The power you need to produce depends roughly on the apparent windspeed, the surface and the slope, as well as the speed you want to ride, the cadence and heart rate being dependent variables (the heart rate being also dependent of the cadence).
Gears give you the possibility to choose the cadence you find the most optimal for the current situation, but you'll need the same power regardless of the gear you're in if you target a given speed for given conditions. What changes when you don't have sufficient range (single gear being the most extreme form) is that when you reach the limit of what you drivetrain allows, you need to deliver more power to keep moving (there's a minimum cadence to be able to deliver power).
It's likely that the difference you noticed between single gear and derailleur have a psychological origin: a derailleur gives you the option to stay longer in your comfort zone, so you take the option. But if you were to ride as fast uphill as you did with your derailleur-equipped bike, you'll have an intense workout as well. I recently encountered this situation when riding with a friend recently, their min ratio was 1, mine 0.7: when hitting steep climbs, they were of course much faster than me because they had no choice (walking not being an option), but if I wanted to follow them, I also needed to deliver a higher power, but I could do it at a higher cadence (but I didn't want to, because I could).
Also, whether it provides a better workout depends on your objective, harder doesn't mean superior. If you want to train for endurance (Z2), that won't be the case for the example. If you train for a specific goal, structured training is probably the best option, and I doubt a single-gear bike will give you enough flexibility.

Assuming that you are not riding on flat terrain at a constant speed, a single speed can provide a different workout. If you have a geared bike you can use it to provide constant pressure, effort and cadence for variable speed by shifting gears. On a geared bike, going up hill is not actually more work than going on flat terrain; you just go slower for the same effort. The same is not true for a single speed bike. Your speed vs effort on a single speed is higher around your ideal cadence, but if going uphill (or against headwind) the power required to find your ideal cadence is of course going to be higher.
The end result of all this is that your power output will likely vary more across a ride if riding without shifting gears. On the flats you will likely have a lower speed than on a geared bike because you cannot maintain a high enough cadence, but you will likely find yourself gunning it up hills at maximum power because going slowly up a hill on a single speed bike is actually more work than doing it at high speed.
It seems likely to me that over a decent distance with some inclines, riding a single speed will be more like interval training, switching between max effort on inclines and relatively low effort on the flat segments.
On a geared bike, you can easily maintain a constant effort, which allow you to go much further distances at a higher average power, and achieve a different type of training.
Which is better depends on what you're after. And ultimately your body tends to get better at doing the thing you're doing. If you want to train yourself to maintain high constant power over long time periods, a geared bike will be better.

There’s no arguing there. On a long (80-100 km) ride it would be tough to infeasible (for me; at this time) to ride a single-speed.

I've done a 150 km ride across the English countryside (lots of rolling hills) on my fixed gear. I can't say I recommend it. My knees were pretty sore for several days afterwards. If you want to optimize for Big Legs, then get a fixed gear bike and do short bursts up the steepest hills you can find.

In the last years there has always been someone who attempted to ride the transcontinental race (https://www.lostdot.cc/tcr) on a fixed gear bike. I'm not sure whether someone of those ever finished the race, but they regularly reached more than 1000km...

As training (for everything) depends on doing it, and doing it depends on liking it enough to keep doing it, riding a bike your like more will help you to train more.
At this time your single speed bike on your routes give you exercise you do not feel you get on your derailleur bikes, so keep using that bike at least part of the time.
But on the other hand, try to make your rides on the other bike(s) more varied, get up, standing on the pedals, do not always shift to the gear most suited to your standard cadans and try out as many variations as you can think up, so you become stronger on the better bike as well.

The main thing that comes to mind is a disadvantage of a single-speed bike: The large forces needed under certain conditions which can actually hurt your knees. When accelerating at slow speeds, riding uphill or riding against the wind: Whenever you would choose a lower gear if you had one, you are now forced to stay in a gear that is larger than you'd like and exert proportionally more force with your legs for the same result.
Whether this actually stresses your knees beyond acceptable limits depends, of course, on all kinds of factors: The terrain, your riding style, your age and your specific physical condition. But one thing is for sure: Knee pain is like back pain — there is a time before the first time and one after the first time, and between the two something happens, and it will never be again as it was before. So try to avoid over-stressing your knees like the plague.

Since I strongly relate to "there is a time before the first time and one after the first time" with respect to back pain and the subsequent measures needed to keep it at bay (sit upright at your desk like a log of wood, etc), thank you for this warning.

@Sam Thanks -- seems I hit a spot ;-).

While we can quibble over the meaning of "workout" I suggest that from your stats it's in many ways a less good one. A workout is training, and training should usually be hard.  Quicker suggests it was easier unless you were pushing yourself harder - an impression I didn't get.
However your description suggests it might have worked rather like an interval session, and they can be quick overall as well as hard.
Since your edit I can provide a similar anomalous anecdote - I snapped the rear derailleur cable on the way to my campsite the night before a big ride, leaving me with just the 3 front gears and a middling sprocket.  I got off to really rather a quick start (before detouring to a bike shop and fitting a new cable in their car park).  Part of that was good riding conditions and setting off with a quick group.

You lost me at “…training should usually be hard. Quicker suggests it was easier…”.
